# Dynamic TextBox scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, textbox, scrollbar

I'm trying to add a verticle scroll bar to my dynamic Textbox.

Here is the code

```
TextBox spellText = new TextBox()   { Multiline = true, ScrollBars.Vertical };
```

I get the error:

> Invalid initializer member declarator

ScrollBars.Verticle = True also does not work.

Comment: Are you sure those properties apply to a TextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, the declaration isn't quite right.  Try this:

```
TextBox spellText = new TextBox() { Multiline = true,
                                    ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical };
```

Comment: +1. It took me several attempts to figure your solution is different from the OP's question. :)